# Image Gradient: Light to Dark, Dark to Light

Tags: image-processing, opencv, c++

From link:

> Black-to-White transition is taken as Positive slope (it has a
>   positive value) while White-to-Black transition is taken as a Negative
>   slope (It has negative value). So when you convert data to np.uint8,
>   all negative slopes are made zero. In simple words, you miss that
>   edge.

So all i want is to write a function so i can keep negative gradient values.
I know how to use Sobel.

[Here is the sobel link](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html) where I got to know light-to-dark, dark-to-light are gradient directions, which are also referred as $+\text ve$ and $-\text ve$ directions.

**IMPROVED Question:**
Please Suggest me a logic of the function to retain only $-\text ve$ values and clip $+\text ve$ values to zero?

***My code:***

```
Sobel(grayImg, grad, CV_16S, 0, 1, -1, BORDER_DEFAULT);
         gradCpy = grad.clone();
         for(uint64_t i=0; i <(gradCpy.rows); i++)
    {
        for(uint64_t j=0; j<(gradCpy.cols); j++)
        {
            if ((gradCpy.data[((gradCpy.step/gradCpy.elemSize()))*i+j]) > 0) {(gradCpy.data[(gradCpy.step/gradCpy.elemSize())*i+j]) = (int32_t)-0.0;} ///nega gradient img
            //if ((gradCpy.data[((gradCpy.step/gradCpy.elemSize()))*i+j]) < 0.0) {gradCpy.data[((gradCpy.step/gradCpy.elemSize()))*i+j] = (int16_t)+0.0;}   ///pos gradient img
        } 
    }
    convertScaleAbs(gradCpy, opImg2);
    imshow("negative grad", opImg2);
```

But i am not getting expected results. As per Sobel link, I want to get edge at black-to-white that is $+\text ve$ gradient and another one at white-to-black that is $-\text ve$ gradient

Comment: Where is $-\text ve$ or $+\text ve$ in your link ?

Comment: positive gradient and negative gradient are one and the same as light-to-dark and dark-to-light gradients.

Answer (score 1):

The UINT8 type is limited to integer numbers on the range [0, 1, 2, ..., 255].
Hence negative values are clipped into 0.

A solution could be wither use other types (Floating Points) or scale and shift.

For instance, given a Floating Point image with values `imageMax` and `imageMean` you can scale it into the `[0, 1, 2, ..., 255]` by doing:

1. Create only positive numbers: `image - imageMin`.
2. Scale it into the range: `round(255 * (image - imageMin) / (imageMax - imageMin))`.

Now the conversion won't loose data.

Others have different approach, set 128 to be zero.
Namely, add 128 to the image, clip it into `[0, 255]` and then convert to `UINT8`.

Enjoy.

Comment: I am aware of uint8 data type. I can use float to preserve values less than zero. What i want is only a logic, which stores negative values and clips positive values to 0.

Comment: What do you mean? Logic of what?

Comment: Please see my question once more.

Comment: I still don't understand...

Comment: @Mandar if you only want to store the negative values, then negate all the gradients *before* you convert the results to a uint8.  Any values that are negative after negation should be set to zero.

Comment: Please check my code. Suggest me improvements. [image-gradients](https://github.com/MandarMG/image-gradients)

Comment: @Mandar, Could you please mark my answer?